# htaccess - moving blog to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

i have a blog, and im moving it to a subdomain. since the URL sintaxis won't be the same, i just want to redirect all url requests that are inside /posts/ to the new subdomain:

**from**

domain.com/posts/xxxxx

**to**

blog.domain.com

this is what i have so far, but it still has to filter only the requests that are **inside** /posts/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewrietRule ^posts/(.*) http://blog.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

... should work.

Comment: nevermind... i was missing the AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php RewriteEngine On

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just need to modify it so that your regular expression in the RewriteRule only matches stuff inside /posts/ as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) http://blog.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hi... it is not working. any of the solutions (which i believe are the same): http://andufo.com/posts/test